# does LaTeX (texlive destribution?) inherit some packages implicitly?

Tags: packages, texlive

My question is based on Detexify symbols base exploration (http://detexify.kirelabs.org/symbols.html), for example I've noticed that multiple integrals like`\iiint` are being provided by either `amsmath` or `esint` package. But I do not remember that I declared these packages in my tex files, but multiple integrals are availible for me, though.

If my statements are correct, how do I know the list of implicitly loaded packages and maybe control them?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have a look at the log file of the document you compile. There are the `.sty` files which are loaded.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\iiint` is not defined by default in latex, so the log should show you which packages are loaded,  or for a nicer list add `\listfiles` to your preamble and then a formatted list of files appears on the terminal and log at the end of the document run.